# Enviar un mensaje a un componente en Angular Electron

Tags: electron

Necesito enviarle un mensaje a un componente de angular. Sistema SPA
Hago lo siguiente:

Desde el componente uno pido:

```
  ipcRenderer.send('titulo-administrador','Daniel');
```

En el Main.ts recibo:

```
ipcMain.on('titulo-administrador', (event, arg) => {
  console.log('arg1:' + arg); // aca veo Daniel, todo bien
  win.webContents.send('titulo-administrador', arg);
});
```

El que deberia recibir el mensaje, es componente dos y tiene:
dentro de dos.html

const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

```
  ipc.on('titulo-administrador', (event, arg) => {
    console.log('arg3:' + arg); //nunca aparece
  })
```

Como me puedo comunicar con el componente dos y que reciba ese arg (mensaje) ?

Comment: Los componentes están siendo utilizados en la misma página?. Es decir son importados o llamados en la misma página de Angular

Comment: Es una SPA, no abro ninguna otra ventana. A eso te referías ?. Son 2 componentes separados.

Comment: Hola me refiero a. Tienes una pagina SPA esta página contiene los componentes que se están visualizando. Los 2 se están ejecutando al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Tema resuelto con injectable